# how to merge two table with different columns in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two table named as `booked_flat` and `master_flat`.

columns of `booked_flats` are

```
customer_name, customer_address, customer_phone, building_wing_no, building_name_no, flat_no
```

columns of `master_flats` are

```
building_wing_no, building_name_no, flat_no, status
```

when any flat get booked the status get change as sold else status remains unsold.

all entries with sold status are in booked_flats.

I have tried to merge this two table but it gives an error please help me

```
$sql =  SELECT * FROM 'booked_flats' 
        UNION SELECT * FROM 'master_flats' 
            WHERE building_wing_no, building_name_no, flat_no NOT IN (
                SELECT building_wing_no, building_name_no, flat_no from booked_flats);
```

example:

```
**master_flat:** 

 building_wing_no building_name_no flat_no status            
 -----------------------------------------------
     a                a2            104   unsold 
 -------------------------------------------------
     b                a3            105    sold




 booked_flat:
  custo_name custo_add custo_ph building_wing_no  building_name_no flat_no
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   harish     wardha     284632        b              a3           105



 I want result like 

  cust_name cust_add custo_ph building_wing_no  building_name_no flat_no status   
     harish    wardha    284632         b            a3             105            
      ---       ---       ---            a           a2             104   unsold
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question like that. Please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is a `join` and not an `union`, but you should update your question and write what you want to display.

```
SELECT * FROM booked_flats b
JOIN master_flats m ON b.building_wing_no = m.building_wing_no
    AND b.building_name_no = m.building_name_no AND b.flat_no = m.flat_no;
```

Comment: but i want all records from booked_flats and some records from master_flats where status = unsold .

Comment: i tried using joins but it gives an error. i am not getting properly how to fetch some records from  table1 and join them with another table.